# Post a url using javascript form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding a few parameters to the url through javascript form submit method. But I am only getting the url i.e. without the added parameters. Is that `input.Type='hidden'` supposed to hide those values from the user or Do you see any issue with my code:

```
function openviewerSelected() {
        var docIds = "C698464D—ODES—4F9E-8684-SFEBDOD6998F, 042D4E06—F656-447D—9439-36$B965D€969, F19842D4-AFE3-4916-947C-07EA2D60198A";
        if (docIds == null || docIds == "") {
            alert("Select atleast one document");
        }
        else {
            var form = document.createElement("form");
            form.setAttribute("method", "post");
            form.setAttribute("action", "http://www.xxxxx.com/token/loginservlet");
            form.setAttribute("target", "_blank");

            var input1 = document.createElement('input');
            input1.type = 'hidden';
            input1.name = 'desktop';
            input1.value = 'PatientAccess';
            form.appendChild(input1);

            var input2 = document.createElement('input');
            input2.type = 'hidden';
            input2.name = 'ecmtoken';
            input2.value = 'rFEKmw7GRXwN%2fjKlRTfW5xkIYf5rnolZjbp0MB1Ag40%3d'; //'123A9B5DB55E123D87E34DB18A3DFD848B216F6D4813F32D9O89E1D942O793BB2D57CCB4E3558E50FD714F22F6EBC123';
            form.appendChild(input2);

            var input3 = document.createElement('input');
            input3.type = 'hidden';
            input3.name = 'docIds';
            input3.value = docIds;
            form.appendChild(input3);

            document.body.appendChild(form);
            form.submit();
            document.body.removeChild(form);
        }
```

I want to append the parameters such as desktop,ecmtoken & docIds in the url.

Comment: Change the form's `method` to `"GET"`

Comment: @phil I guess you are right. my bad, removed my answer.. I am not sure how GET will fix this issue.

Comment: @prashanth OP wants the form params in the URL

Comment: How are you receiving the parameters on the other end? PHP?

Comment: @Phil Thanks! I am getting the values in url with the get. But can we achieve the same with a post request? I mean i want to make sure these parameters are passing even with the post request.It doesn't matter if it shows on url or not.

Comment: @MACMAN that is a link to a viewer actually.with the  posted document ids, the other team has to fetch the docIds based on token based authentication.

Comment: I think you may have to check with the other team whether they are getting the parameters correctly. To my understanding the post parameters will not be visible on the url.